# How to use \R in java 8 regex

Tags: regex, java-8

I am trying to use the new [\R](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) regex matcher from java 8.
However, for the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "This is \r\n a String with \n Different Newlines \r and other things.";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\R", s));
    if (Pattern.matches("\\R", s)) // <-- is always false
    {
      System.out.println("Matched");
    }

    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\R", "<br/>")); //This is a String with <br/> Different Newlines <br/> and other things.
  }
```

The `Pattern.matches` always returns false, where as the `replaceAll` method does seem to find a match and does what I want it to. How do I make the Pattern.matches work ?

I have also tried the long about way and still can't get it to work :

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\R");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: I was looking for information about the Java regex construct `\\R` and found this question, while the duplicate does not mention it. This accepted answer explains what `\\R` is, but also talks about the difference between `.matches` and `.find` as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well `matches` (both in `String` and `Matchers` classes) attempts to match the complete input string.

You need to use `matcher.find` instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\R");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean b = m.find();
System.out.println(b);
```

From [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

`\R`    Matches any Unicode line-break sequence, that is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

PS; If you want to know if input contains a line-break then this one liner will work for you:

```
boolean b = s.matches("(?s).*?\\R.*");
```

Note use of `.*` on either side of `\R` to make sure we are matching complete input. Also you need `(?s)` to enable `DOTALL` mode to be able to match multiline string with `.*`

Comment: So is it wrong to use `(Pattern.matches("\\R", s)` ? I think what I am looking for is a one line solution

Comment: Yes it will fail the match unless input string is just a single line-break

Comment: Sweet. Any suggestions for how all of this can be made into a one easy to read liner ?

Comment: `boolean b = s.matches(".*\\R.*");` returns false

Comment: Sorry, another edit. You need `(?s)` to enable `DOTALL`.

Comment: Thanks @Holger for good optimization tip (edited).